# FragmentDialog staying in front of the status bar, while the application is not on fullscreen

Tags: android, user-interface, android-dialogfragment, android-statusbar

I'm developing an application, and I have a DialogFragment with an edit text and some other information.

Everything looks fine, except on devices with API >= 21, when I click on the editText and the keyboard appears. The FragmentDialog stays in front of the status bar:

[image]

(The white part is my DialogFragment)

The main activity already has android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on manifest.
Is there a way to keep the status bar in front of the FragmentDialog?

**EDIT**: I saw that when the dialog appears, the black dim background is applied on all screen, including status bar. I think that's because the dialog appears in front of the status bar. Is it possible applying the dim background below status bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a fullscreen dialog specified by Material design.
Put this code in the DialogFragment:

```
 @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }
```

Call this dialog by:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, FullScreenDialog.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Quick workaround is to set a top margin of 24dp in the base layout.